# how to display telugu font from logcat to android mobile

Tags: android, fonts

i  am trying to display some text which is in Telugu Font. When Iam testing, I found telugu text is displayed in logcat in android but it is not displaying on my android mobile.. I just followed the below code line to display the Telugu font.

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"vemana2000.ttf");
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myFont);
tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: have you added vemana2000.ttf font into your Assets folder?

Answer (score 0):

Supported Languages are

```
Language / Locale                 Supported since version

English, US (en_US)               1.1
German, Germany (de_DE)           1.1
Chinese, PRC (zh_CN)              1.5
Chinese, Taiwan (zh_TW)           1.5
Czech, Czech Republic (cs_CZ)     1.5
Dutch, Belgium (nl_BE)            1.5
Dutch, Netherlands (nl_NL)        1.5
English, Australia (en_AU)        1.5
English, Britain (en_GB)          1.5
English, Canada (en_CA)           1.5
English, New Zealand (en_NZ)      1.5
English, Singapore(en_SG)         1.5
French, Belgium (fr_BE)           1.5
French, Canada (fr_CA)            1.5
French, France (fr_FR)            1.5
French, Switzerland (fr_CH)       1.5
German, Austria (de_AT)           1.5
German, Liechtenstein (de_LI)     1.5
German, Switzerland (de_CH)       1.5
Italian, Italy (it_IT)            1.5
Italian, Switzerland (it_CH)      1.5
Japanese (ja_JP)                  1.5
Korean (ko_KR)                    1.5
Polish (pl_PL)                    1.5
Russian (ru_RU)                   1.5
Spanish (es_ES)                   1.5
Arabic, Egypt (ar_EG)             2.3
Arabic, Israel (ar_IL)            2.3
Bulgarian, Bulgaria (bg_BG)       2.3
Catalan, Spain (ca_ES)            2.3
Croatian, Croatia (hr_HR)         2.3
Danish, Denmark(da_DK)            2.3
English, India (en_IN)            2.3
English, Ireland (en_IE)          2.3
English, Zimbabwe (en_ZA)         2.3
Finnish, Finland (fi_FI)          2.3
Greek, Greece (el_GR)             2.3
Hebrew, Israel (iw_IL)*           2.3
Hindi, India (hi_IN)              2.3
Hungarian, Hungary (hu_HU)        2.3
Indonesian, Indonesia (in_ID)*    2.3
Latvian, Latvia (lv_LV)           2.3
Lithuanian, Lithuania (lt_LT)     2.3
Norwegian-Bokmol, Norway(nb_NO)   2.3
Portuguese, Brazil (pt_BR)        2.3
Portuguese, Portugal (pt_PT)      2.3
Romanian, Romania (ro_RO)         2.3
Serbian (sr_RS)                   2.3
Slovak, Slovakia (sk_SK)          2.3
Slovenian, Slovenia (sl_SI)       2.3
Spanish, US (es_US)               2.3
Swedish, Sweden (sv_SE)           2.3
Tagalog, Philippines (tl_PH)      2.3
Thai, Thailand (th_TH)            2.3
Turkish, Turkey (tr_TR)           2.3
Ukrainian, Ukraine (uk_UA)        2.3
Vietnamese, Vietnam (vi_VN)       2.3
```

Comment: how can i display telugu text in my mobile using those version?

Comment: Use NTR.ttf font UTF16/UTF-8. http://www.generalfiles.pw/download/gs61d00066h32i0/NTR.ttf.html

Answer (score 0):

Use NTR.ttf font UTF16/UTF-8. I worked with it over a year ago & was successful.

Answer (score 0):

I used following code but unable to display the telugu word properly 
Any help from anyone??`txtview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtview);
Typeface textf=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Lohit-Telugu.ttf");
        txtview.setText("స్వాగతం");
txtview.setTypeface(textf);`